# Ways to say "doomed to a horrible fate"

Tags: idiomatic-language

We have a local/regional Italian saying that literally sounds like "to be prey for the cat", which depicts how you would be doomed to a horrible fate (as any little animal/insect that becomes a prey for it!), normally used with a figurative meaning.
Is there a common equivalent in English?

Comment: A slang expression that seems to have become popular recently is _to be toast_ (see [this](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/toast) and scroll down). I don't know why, except that toast is a common breakfast food.

Comment: A common but far less illustrative phrase is, *His fate was sealed,* meaning he could not escape what was in store.  *When Robert pressed the large, red button that read, "Do not press this button," his fate was sealed.*

Comment: Can you give an example where "to be prey for the cat" would be a natural? It'll help us see if any English expression is a good equivalent. Is it only for physical peril, or financial or political ruin too? Does it have to be a horrible fate happening soon or can it be an unavoidable doom  in the future?

Comment: @KateBunting If I recall,  "to be toast" was coined in *Ghostbusters*, when Bill Murray changed his line from "turn into toast".  https://www.businessinsider.in/miscellaneous/9-common-words-you-probably-didnt-know-came-from-movies/slidelist/64310419.cms

Comment: @gotube Let me try with these: _"Hey, we've just lost the last night train! We are ..."_ / _"I've broken the last spare part for the engine, here in the middle of nowhere: I'm ..."_. All those cases where you feel hopeless, not necessarily for a matter of life and death, can be just figurative

Answer (score -1):

In English, we often refer to a "cornered rat". For example (from [The Globe and Mail](https://www.theglobeandmail.com/opinion/article-putin-is-increasingly-a-cornered-rat-this-could-make-him-even-more/)):

> Putin is increasingly a cornered rat. This could make him even more dangerous

Similar to your cat's prey, a cornered rat faces a terrible impending situation and has no way of escaping it.

Comment: A cornered rat is *in a tight spot* but I'm not sure that it's doomed to a horrible fate.  Being *prey for the cat* probably doesn't make the mouse more dangerous.

Comment: @EllieK In general, being a cornered rat doesn't make someone more dangerous, either. That is just a particular situation in that article.